# How to draw line chart for Flutter app?

Tags: dart, flutter

At the moment, I have found 2 ways that could be used to draw line, which possibly could be improved into a line chart:

1. using `canvas.drawCircle(..)` and `canvas.drawLine(..)`

   ```
    canvas.drawCircle(new Offset(2.0, 5.0), 10.0, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(new Offset(50.0, 100.0), 10.0, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(new Offset(2.0, 5.0), new Offset(50.0, 100.0), paint);
   ```

   [image: point_line]
2. using `canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.lines, ..)` I prefer #2, because I can pass all points into one function `canvas.drawPoints(..)`.

   ```
    List offsetList = [new Offset(2.0, 5.0), new Offset(50.0, 100.0),];
    canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.lines, offsetList, paint);
   ```

   [image: line]

Paint object:

```
    final paint = new Paint()
  ..color = Colors.blue[400]
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
   ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
```

**Question:**

At the moment, I think #2 is a better way to draw line chart, but how can I make the points visible like #1? Do you know any other better ways that could be use to draw line chart?

Answer (score 8):

I am sure by now you are not worrying about this anymore so for anyone that would like another way. You can also use `canvas.drawPath(...)`, here is a simple implementation for a line graph using it.

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  canvas.translate(0.0, size.height);
  final Path path = new Path();
  final Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.color = Colors.blue[100];  
  final double center = size.height/2;
  path.moveTo(0.0, 0.0); // first point in bottom left corner of container
  List<double> ypos = [10.0, 40.0, 100.0, 60.0, 40.0, 55.0, 200.0]; // random y points
  path.lineTo(0.0, - (ypos[0] + center)); // creates a point translated in y inline with leading edge
  final int dividerCnst = ypos.length; // number of points in graph
  for(int i = 1; i < dividerCnst + 1; i++){
    path.lineTo(size.width/dividerCnst * i - size.width/(dividerCnst * 2), - (ypos[i-1] + center));
  }
  path.lineTo(size.width, -(ypos[dividerCnst - 1] + center)); // the last point in line with trailing edge
  path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0); // last point in bottom right corner of container
  path.close();
  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  canvas.restore();
}
```

(0,0) is top left so to change this I do `canvas.translate(0.0, size.height)` to translate the origin to the bottom left corner. In Fluttr +ve is downwards to the Y values are negative and I have added it to the variable center so my point don't lie at the bottom but higher up. This result returns this.

[image]

Hope this helps someone. Peace.